# counting session units from array PHP

Tags: php

I want to count my $_SESSION['cart'] (units) products from my basket.

```
#check added stock
            $units = (int) $_POST['units'];
        $sizes_id = (int) $_POST['size_id'];

        $in_stock = $db->GetScalar("SELECT p.units FROM products_sizes s 
                                    INNER JOIN products p ON p.product_id = s.product_id
                                    WHERE s.id = '$sizes_id' LIMIT 1");

        $total = isset($_SESSION['cart'][$sizes_id]) ? $_SESSION['cart'][$sizes_id]['units'] : 0;
        $total += $units;

        if($total <= $in_stock) {
            if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$sizes_id])) {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$sizes_id]['units'] = $total;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$sizes_id] = array('size' => $sizes_id, 'units' => $total);
            }
            $msg = 'Added';
            $status = 1;
        }else {
            $msg = 'Product is not in the basket';
            $status = 0;
        }
```

This is how the output looks like

```
Array(

[57] => Array
    (
        [size] => 57
        [units] => 5
    )

[56] => Array
    (
        [size] => 56
        [units] => 1
   )
```

`)`

Comment: Ok I am not sure if I got your question, should the answer be 2 or 6 here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here goes

```
<?php
    $total_units = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
        $total_units += $value['units'];
    }

echo $total_units;
```

?>

Should get the answer

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
$numUnits = 0;

foreach ($yourArray as $item)
    $numUnits += $item['units'];
```